# How to configure the Publication Date Module for 6x

Tags: datetime

I have a Drupal 6 site with a publishing workflow. I'm trying to set it up so that News articles have the Published date on them instead of the default, creation date. There's a Publication Module for Drupal 6. I've installed and activated that module, but am now at a loss for how to get this field into my News content type. I'm a non-programmer, so need to know using the Drupal interface, if that's possible.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Reading module's page documentation, seems no configuration needed except permission.

Comment: I turned on the Publication Date Module and then went to the permissions page but I don't see a listing for it. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: Check the `hook_permission` implementation in .module file. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, I'm not a programmer. Can you offer more assistance than this--Like try removing this code and replacing it with this? If not, I understand. Thanks!